# How make this operation (+=) in time span in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

This code returns me an error and I want to make this operation:

```
foreach (var item in db.Panchers)
{
    string x = "00:00:00";
    TimeSpan zero = TimeSpan.Parse(x);
    item.AllDate = zero;
    foreach (var items in db.Times.Where(items => items.Name == item.Pancher1))
    {
        TimeSpan span += items.All.Value;
        decimal m = Convert.ToDecimal((item.AllDate).Value.TotalMinutes);
        decimal h = m / 60;
        item.AllDate=h;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

My error is in the line `TimeSpan span += items.All.Value`.

Comment: Please provide the error.

Comment: I have a hard time not getting terminally distracted by a combination of panchers and dates.

Comment: Anyway... maybe you should explain what you're trying to achieve. It looks like you simply want the sum of `TimeSpan`s.

Answer (score 3):

The `+=` operator can only be used with existing variables since it takes the current value of the variable and adds some other value to it before assigning the result back to the variable. In a way the following two expressions are equivalent:

```
x += y;
x = x + y;
```

Since the variable on the left side needs to have a value before, the `+=` operator cannot appear with a variable declaration. So you first need to declare the variable, assign a value to it and then you can use the `+=` operator.

For example:

```
// declare the variable, and assign a zero timespan to it
TimeSpan span = TimeSpan.Zero;

// use the += operator to add an hour
span += TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
```

Comment: I can't solve it, I want to make foreach on db and return me total of this field(items.All) that include many times, then save it in another field (TimeSpan span += items.All.Value;)